# Missing 'Workflow Association Form' from SharePoint 2010 templates in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, workflow

I am trying follow a tutorial on creating a Workflow using VS2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231590.aspx

However under the section 'Adding an Association Form to the Workflow', I need to add a new item to the project of type 'Workflow Association Form' however it doesn't appear in my list of templates. Do I need to download these templates from somewhere?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I mean did you find the missing Workflow Association Form template? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

You have to click on, for example if you have default names for your workflow poject, then click on "workflow1" and then you'll get Asssociation Form

Comment: If Add -> New Item is triggered from the project node (in solution explorer), you won't see these templates; if Add -> New Item is triggered from the *.cs file for your workflow, you will see the Association and Instantiation forms. They seem to be context sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

right click on the expense - workflow1; you will be adding the form to the workflow itself, not the solution/project